# Windows 7 - Multiple VLANs on one machine on one interface

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, vlan

In OS X, I can set up my computer so that I can use multiple VLANs on one machine, using the same interface. For example, I can connect my Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter to my network. I can then setup (in the Networking section of System Preferences) multiple VLAN interfaces. For example, I can have (in addition to the primary TB Ethernet interface) one interface for VLAN 1, an interface for VLAN 2, and one for VLAN 3.

I'm looking to accomplish this in Windows 7 as well. One interface for the "native" network, and some for VLANs.

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

If it matters, my networking hardware is a box running PfSense connected to a Unifi US-8, and a UAP-AC-Pro, MacBook Pro, and an Intel Nuc (the above referenced Windows 7 Machine) connected to the switch.

Comment: VLAN support is provided through the network card driver in Windows 7.  If it exists, it will be under Adapter properties -> VLANs.

Answer (score 2):

Windows client/workstation itself does not implement VLAN support.

Drivers for some network cards implement VLAN support.  In particular, Intel's PROSet software suite for most of their add-on cards has this functionality.  I don't know if the NIC on the NUC (heh) supports this.  Look in Device Manager, find the network adapter, bring up properties, and look for an "Advanced" tab.  If you don't see it, try checking Intel's website for the latest driver software for the NIC on that platform.